# Link user to Play Store App from a webpage

Tags: android

Is there any way to link a user to the Play Store app from within a webpage or web view? Ideally how it would work is the user clicks the link, and the Play Store app immediately opens as it does if you send the user there from within an app.

Every time I've gone to a link from a webpage it's ended up sending me to the web version of the play store, not the app -- is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the first answer, I misunderstood your question, here's the edit:
this link from a webpage should really work (it work for me as well!)

```
<a href="market://details?id={package_name}" target="_top">App</a>
```

obviously you should think about catching the case in which user hasn't Play Store installed in the phone..

source is the same: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

Comment: I want to have it launch when the user clicks the link in a webpage, so I can't use native Android code to open the play store when the link is clicked.

Comment: @BillL sorry I misundertood what you were asking: edited the answer

Comment: Anytime I enter that link into my browser, it just brings me to a Google search page. Could that be because you're not supposed to enter it directly? I can't imagine that would be why but I'm not sure why that link never works for me.